# two condition after where clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query which is not working

```
$lokesh = "select * from license_info where mac_id='$mac_id' and admin_user_name='$admin'";
```

In above query I am selecting record where macid and admin_user_name where matched

But while I echo this sql query it show output like

```
select * from license_info where mac_id='0800279020F2' and admin_user_name='sanjay
'
```

last single quotes is printing in below line so I am not able to retrive record. What is the reason of printing single quotes in below line

Comment: User enters his username and then presses enter

Comment: you may also use trim() to remove whitespaces in the php variables before firing the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that your variable `$admin` contains a newline in the end. Remove it and there will be no problem with this.

You will, however, have a possible SQL injection attack. Use parameters, not inline values.

Comment: Very intelligent answer. I got my solution. Thank you.

Comment: I am exploding one special character and last array value is user name so problem is come.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `br` or `new line feed tag` and execute it..
and use validation

```
$admin=htmlspecialchars($admin);
```

**`htmlspecialchars()` to avoid sql injection**

or use **htmlentities**

```
$admin=htmlentities($admin);
```